# Xamarin Forms WebView issue with camera on IPhone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.forms

I've written a small app where I want to open a web page (inside my content page using webview). The page needs the access to the camera of my phone. The issue is that there's only a message from the page that there's no access to the camera. Getting access through Xamarin.Essentials doesn't help. Opening the same page with Safari on the same device works, asking me if I want to give the permission to use the camera
Any ideas how to solve that?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Here is a similar native iOS discussion from Apple Forums (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/134216) , you can have a look at that . The most important part is the `NSCameraUsageDescription`  must be present inside the `info.plist` .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT thank you. It seems that this is not possible because the element doesn't support that. I've to di that outside my app.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems not to be possible due to lacking support of the base component of webview (webkit) I'll close this ..for now :)
If you're interested on this topic have a look on http://www.openradar.me/33571214 (3 years old but still true)